# Remove last character of string in Apache Velocity templating language not working

Tags: java, velocity

I am trying to convert markdown hyperlinks into html hyperlinks in the Apache Velocity template language (for Marketo). I am nearly there by splitting on ']' and then removing the first character from the remaining '[link text' piece, and the first and last characters from the remaining '(url)' piece.

It will let me remove the first character in each, but doesn't like my code for removing the last character. This is simple code so I don't know why it isn't working.

```
#set( $refArr = $reference.split(']',2) )
<li>
    <a href=$refArr[1].substring(1,$refArr[1].length()-1)>$refArr[0].substring(1)</a>
</li>
```

It just doesn't like the '-1' part, see error. Velocity is supposed to have full Java method access, but it appears that it may be confusing Java for html.

```
Cannot get email content- <div>An error occurred when procesing the email Body! </div> <p>Encountered "-1" near</p>
```

I've also tried using regex with the replace method as well but that doesn't work either, whether with the '(' character escaped, double escaped, or not escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to use the MathTool class for Velocity:

```
#set( $refArr = $reference.split(']',2) )
<li>
    <a href=$refArr.get(1).substring(1,$math.sub($refArr.get(1).length(),1))>$refArr.get(0).substring(1)</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work in recent versions, otherwise you can do it in two steps:

```
#set($len = $refArr.get(1).length() - 1)
<a href=$refArr[1].substring(1,$len)>$refArr[0].substring(1)</a>
```